# <% if I18n.locale == 'es' %> doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

In my head.html.erb I have this

```
Language: <%= I18n.locale %>
<% if I18n.locale == 'es' %>This is Spanish
<% else % >This is NOT Spanish
<% end %>
```

But I see

```
Language: es
This is not Spanish
```

How is it possible?!

I try to use <% if I18n.locale = 'es' %>, but the message "This is Spanish" is showed also if the I18n.locale is de, en, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`I18n.locale` returns a symbol, not a string. You need to compare against `:es`, not `'es'`.

```
.irb(main):001:0> I18n.locale
=> :en
irb(main):002:0> I18n.locale == 'en'
=> false
irb(main):003:0> I18n.locale == :en
=> true
```